# Discrepancy in results of floor division operator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I noticed something weird today with floor division:

```
>>> 10.1/1.01
10.0
>>> 10.1//1.01
9.0

>>> 2688937/268893.7
10.0
>>> 2688937//268893.7
9.0

>>> 6.6/3.3
2.0
>>> 6.6//3.3
2.0
```

I assume this is due to floating point error but was wondering if there might be some other reason that 10.0 seems to get floored to 9.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can inspect the *exact* decimal expansion of a floating point number by using string formatting with the `format` function:

```
>>> format(10.1, '.70f')
'10.0999999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375000000000000000000000'
>>> format(1.01, '.70f')
'1.0100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625000000000000000000'
```

And it is suddenly very clear: the binary [significand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand) closest to the 10.1 is *slightly smaller* in magnitude than the exact number, whereas that closest to 1.01 is slightly *larger* than the exact.

However, the actual result of `10.1 / 1.01` is rounded to 10.0 *exact* because *that* one is the value *closest to the result of division*:

```
>>> format(10.1 / 1.01, '.f')
'10.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
```

but the flooring division *first* rounds *downwards*, and then floors down to the integer.

More specifically, [`float.__floordiv__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/floatobject.c#L664) in CPython calls [`float_divmod`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/floatobject.c#L617) which in turn uses the [`fmod` C standard library function](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.12.10.1) to find the floating point remainder of the division. The description of `fmod` in C standard library is

> **Description**
>
> 2. The `fmod` functions compute the floating-point remainder of `x/y`.
>
> **Returns**
>
> 3. The `fmod` functions return the value `x - ny`, for some integer `n` such that, if `y` is nonzero, the result has the same sign as `x` and magnitude less than the magnitude of `y`. If `y` is zero, whether a domain error occurs or the `fmod` functions return zero is implementation- defined.

The `fmod` function is available as [`math.fmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.fmod) in CPython standard library.

---

The result of `math.fmod(10.1, 1.01)` is

```
>>> format(math.fmod(10.1, 1.01), '.70f')
'1.0099999999999995647925743469386361539363861083984375000000000000000000'
```

and if we subtract this from the `10.1` and round the result to the closest exact integer, we get `9`.

Comment: Equivalently `'%.70f' % 10.1`, `'{:.70f}'.format(10.1)`, or `f'{10.1:.70f}'`.